# imacros can't write in text field facebook

Tags: facebook, imacros

**HELP PLEASEEEE....**
 :(  :(  :(

i'm trying to make imacros code for input product at facebook shop in facebook page.

it didn't want to write anything at product title, price and description field.

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqcTN.jpg)

my code is:

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

SET !DATASOURCE 1.csv
SET !LOOP 3
WAIT SECONDS=1

URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/mine/shop#
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:_5tqv&&TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>Photos
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=* CONTENT=C:\{{!COL2}}
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=3 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>Photos
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=* CONTENT=C:\{{!COL28}}
WAIT SECONDS=10
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Use<SP>Photos<SP>(2)
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=TYPE:text&&CLASS:_58al&&PLACEHOLDER:Name&&NAME:productTitle&&MAXLENGTH:80 CONTENT={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=CLASS:_4b7k<SP>_4b7k_atlas&&PLACEHOLDER:0 CONTENT={{!COL4}}
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=CLASS:_58an&&ROWS:3&&PLACEHOLDER:Description<SP>(Optional)&&NAME:productDescription CONTENT={{!COL1}}<BR><BR>Warna:<SP>{{!COL7}}<BR>Bahan:<SP>{{!COL8}}<BR>Size:<SP>{{!COL9}}<BR>Sol:<SP>{{!COL10}}<BR>{{!COL11}}<BR><BR>Harga:<SP>{{!COL4}}<BR><BR>{{!COL26}}<BR><BR>{{!COL13}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Save
WAIT SECONDS=3
REFRESH
```

Thank youuuu so muchh before...

Comment: To write something into the text fields, try 'Experimental event recording mode' in 'iMacros' for Firefox.

Comment: Thank you so muchhh...it works :)